# Partial Fraction confusion

Tags: partial-fractions

How to solve this using partial fraction $$\frac{x^2+7}{(2x-1)(x-1)}$$

I am using $\frac{A}{2x-1}+\frac{B}{x-1}$ but not getting it

Comment: You have to first perform division. You can only split into partial fractions if the enumerator is of lower degree than denominator.

Answer (score 1):

First perform long division:
\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+7}{(2x-1)(x-1)}&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{13}{2}}{(2x-1)(x-1)}
\end{align}
Then, put
$$\frac{\frac{3}{2}x+\frac{13}{2}}{(2x-1)(x-1)}=\frac{A}{2x-1}+\frac{B}{x-1}$$

Comment: why 1/2 is taken out side

Comment: @MilanAmrutJoshi: It is consequence of the long division.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Subtract $-8$ and add back $8$ to $x^2+7$.